# Customize Subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats, subfig

for a report, I need to set subfigures in the following way:

1. enumerate each subfigure with a capital letter (A, B, C, etc) and place it at the left top of the image.
2. Collect captions beneath the whole figure (Fig XY. bla bla bla (A) bla (B) bla (C) bla).

I absolutely don't know how to get there and haven't found any advice elsewhere on the internet. So any help is highly appreciated.

Currently, my code is as followed:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl} 
 \usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage[]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,format=plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[ caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{Figure1.eps}\label{subfig:1}}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\subfloat[caption 2 ]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{Figure2.eps}\label{subfig:2}}
\newline
\subfloat[caption 3]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{Figure3.eps}\label{subfig:3}}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\subfloat[caption 4]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{Figure4.eps}\label{subfig:4}}
\caption{caption of the whole figure}\label{fig}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

PS The whole report should look like the journal "Biochemistry" from ACS.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Your MWE /Minimal Working Example is not complete, mised is package `subfig˙...

Answer (score 2):

A place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType[Alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=0.25cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{subfloatrow}
    \fcapside[\FBwidth]
      {\caption{\label{fig:subfig-a}}}
      {\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \end{subfloatrow}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{subfloatrow}[2]
    \fcapside[\FBwidth]
      {\caption{\label{fig:subfig-b}}}
      {\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \end{subfloatrow}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{subfloatrow}
    \fcapside[\FBwidth]
      {\caption{\label{fig:subfig-c}}}
      {\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \end{subfloatrow}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{subfloatrow}[2]
    \fcapside[\FBwidth]
      {\caption{\label{fig:subfig-d}}}
      {\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \end{subfloatrow}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A caption text that references the individual images: \subref{fig:subfig-a} shows ..., \subref{fig:subfig-b}, \subref{fig:subfig-c} and \subref{fig:subfig-d}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! It is exactly what I need :D

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\captionsetup{font=small, format=plain}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering\floatsetup[subfigure]{capposition=top, captionskip=1ex}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\ffigbox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}}{\caption{caption 1}\label{subfig:1}}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}}{\caption{caption 2}\label{subfig:2}}
\end{subfloatrow}\vskip 4ex

\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}}{\caption{caption 3}\label{subfig:3}}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}}{\caption{caption 4}\label{subfig:4}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}%
{\caption{caption of the whole figure}\label{fig}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]